# Передача подписавшемуся объекту измененных свойств объекта наблюдаемого класса

Tags: c#, события, properties

Всем доброго дня!

Возник следующий вопрос:

Есть класс. например Книга Book, в котором определен набор свойств.

```
public class Book {
    string Name {get; set;}
    string Author {get; set;}
    double price {get; set;}

    // Далее определено Событие на изменение свойств книги OnBookPropertiesChanged
}
```

Допустим, на событие OnBookPropertiesChanged объекта класса Book подпишется другой объект определенного класса. Как этому объекту передать измененное значение какого-либо свойства объекта класса Book?

При этом интересно: есть ли способ избежать создания отдельных событий на изменение каждого отдельного свойства объекта класса Book? Дело в том, что свойств у Book может быть много. (Подразумевается, что они вводятся в отдельную форму в программе для последующего сохранения в объекте класса).

Есть вариант поступить следующим образом:

```
public interface IBook {
    string Name { get; }
    string Author { get; }
    double Price { get; }
}

public class Book : IBook {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Author { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; private set; }

    public Book(string name, string author, double price) {
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
        Price = price;
    }

    public void UpdateBookProperties(IBook newBookProperties) {
        this.Name = newBookProperties.Name;
        this.Author = newBookProperties.Author;
        this.Price = newBookProperties.Price;

        OnBookPropertiesChanged();
    }

    public event Action<IBook> BookPropertiesChanged;

    private void OnBookPropertiesChanged() {
        if(BookPropertiesChanged != null) {
            IBook newBookProperties = 
                BookFactory.CreateBook(this.Name, this.Author, this.Price);

            BookPropertiesChanged(newBookProperties);
        }
    }
}

public class BookFactory {
    public static IBook CreateBook(string name, string author, double price) {
        return new Book(name, author, price);
    }
}
```

Но такой вариант мне не нравится. Причин несколько:

1) Для изменения какого-либо из свойств текущего объекта класса Book необходимо создавать новый объект, в котором будут указаны новые свойства.

2) И, как следствие, нет возможности простого изменения отдельно взятого свойства книги. Иначе объект, подписанный на событие BookPropertiesChanged просто не увидит изменение свойства книги.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать подобный сценарий без избытка кода?

Comment: Для передачи данных через событие используют класс, который наследует `EventArgs`, экземпляр этого класса выступает в качестве второго параметра после первого параметра `sender` в событии.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ). Я знаю про этот класс. Но в текущей реализации, даже при использовании EventArgs все равно будут передаваться все свойства книги разом: как измененные, так и не измененные. Я ищу более гибкий вариант, исключающий недостатки той реализации, пример которой я привел в основном сообщении.

Comment: Похожая система работает в WPF в байдинге свойств. Класс ViewModel имеет свойства с оповещением по событию `PropertyChanged()` при вызове которого передается в качестве параметра название свойства. Когда контрол во View получает это такое событие - он перечитывает значение этого свойства, к которому он привязан.

Comment: В паттернах проектирования такой паттерн называется Observer, если я не ошибаюсь. Поищите его реализацию.

Comment: В данном случае подписка на событие, если я не ошибаюсь, и есть реализация данного паттерна проектирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно слать сообщения из сеттеров пропертей

Типа

namespace mvvm

{

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(object sender, Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpresssion);
        OnPropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public static class PropertySupport
{
    public static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        if (propertyExpresssion == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpresssion");
        }

        var memberExpression = propertyExpresssion.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpresssion");
        }

        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpresssion");
        }

        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
        if (getMethod.IsStatic)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The referenced property is a static property.", "propertyExpresssion");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}

public class Book : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _author;
    private double _price;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (!_name.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(this, () => Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get { return _author; }
        set
        {
            if (!_author.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                _author = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(this, () => Author);
            }
        }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            if (_price != value)
            {
                _price = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(this, () => Price);
            }
        }
    }
}

class BookUser
{
    public void ObserveBook(Book book)
    {
        book.PropertyChanged += Book_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Book_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var book = sender as Book;
        if (book != null)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => book.Author))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Author is changed");
            }
            if (e.PropertyName == PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => book.Name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name is changed");
            }
            if (e.PropertyName == PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => book.Price))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Price is changed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за интересную и гибкую реализацию! Я пока остановился на своем варианте).

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 2):

Всем большое спасибо за код и подсказки.

В результате остановился на следующей реализации:

```
// Описывает передаваемое свойство, 
// значение которого было изменено в соответствующем классе
public interface ITransferredArgs {
    // Название измененного свойства
    string PropertyName { get; }

    // Новое значение, присвоенное свойству
    object PropertyValue { get; }
}

public interface IBook {
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }
    double Price { get; set; }

    event Action<ITransferredArgs> BookPropertiesChanged;
}

public class BookArgs : ITransferredArgs {
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public BookArgs( string propertieName, object propertieValue ) {
        this.PropertyName = propertieName;
        this.PropertyValue = propertieValue;
    }
}

public class Book : IBook {
    string name;
    string author;
    double price;

    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return name;
        }
        set {
            if(name != value) {
                name = value;
                OnBookPropertiesChanged(GetPropertyCallerName(), value);
            }
        }
    }
    public string Author {
        get {
            return author;
        }
        set {
            if(author != value) {
                author = value;
                OnBookPropertiesChanged(GetPropertyCallerName(), value);
            }
        }
    }
    public double Price {
        get {
            return price;
        }
        set {
            if(price != value) {
                price = value;
                OnBookPropertiesChanged(GetPropertyCallerName(), value);
            }
        }
    }

    public Book(string name) {
        FirstName = name;
    }

    ~Book() {
        BookPropertiesChanged = null;
    }

    string GetPropertyCallerName([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
        return propertyName;
    }

    public void UpdateBookProperties(IBook newBookProperties) {
        this.FirstName = newBookProperties.FirstName;
        this.Author = newBookProperties.Author;
        this.Price = newBookProperties.Price;
    }

    public event Action<ITransferredArgs> BookPropertiesChanged;

    private void OnBookPropertiesChanged(string propertieName, object propertieValue) {
        if(BookPropertiesChanged != null) {
            ITransferredArgs newBookProperties = 
                BookFactory.CreateBookArgs( propertieName, propertieValue );

            BookPropertiesChanged(newBookProperties);
        }
    }
}

public class BookFactory {
    public static IBook CreateBook(string name) {
        return new Book(name);
    }

    public static IBook CreateBook(IBook book) {
        Book newBook = new Book(book.Author);
        newBook.FirstName = book.FirstName;
        newBook.Price = book.Price;
        return newBook;
    }

    public static ITransferredArgs CreateBookArgs(string propertieName, object propertieValue) {
        return new BookArgs(propertieName, propertieValue);
    }
}

public class Visiter {
    // Наблюдаемая книга
    public IBook observableBook;

    public Visiter(IBook book) {
        // Подписываемся на событие изменения наблюдаемой книги
        book.BookPropertiesChanged += OnBookDataChanged;

        // Копируем данные (не ссылку) в объект observableBook.
        observableBook = BookFactory.CreateBook(book);
    }

    // Обновляем параметры наблюдаемой книги
    public void OnBookDataChanged(ITransferredArgs args) {
        // Получаем название изменяемого свойства
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = observableBook.GetType().GetProperty(args.PropertyName);

        // Обновляем соответствующее свойство в observableBook
        propertyInfo.SetValue(observableBook, args.PropertyValue);
        /*
        // Альтернативный вариант, требующий изменения названия поля
        // в case при изменении названия соответствующего поля в наблюдаемом классе
        switch(args.PropertyName) {
            case ("FirstName"):
                observableBook.FirstName = (string)args.PropertyValue;
                break;
            case ("Author"):
                observableBook.Author = (string)args.PropertyValue;
                break;
            case ("Price"):
                observableBook.Price = (double)args.PropertyValue;
                break;
        }*/
    }

    // Вывести информацию о наблюдаемой книге
    public void ShowObservableBook() {
        Console.WriteLine("Имя наблюдаемой книги = " + observableBook.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("Автор наблюдаемой книги = " + observableBook.Author);
        Console.WriteLine("Цена наблюдаемой книги = " + observableBook.Price + "\n");
    }
}
```